# How did Ross get tickets to Sting's concert?

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

In the tenth episode of the eighth season of Friends, Phoebe tries  to get tickets to Sting's concert and fails miserably.

However, in the end of the chapter, turns out that Ross did get tickets, and he just gives them to her nonchalantly, as if it's an obvious thing.

So, how did Ross get the tickets? Is it explained somewhere and I missed it?

Comment: "fails miserably" — I mean, she does get to see inside Sting's New York home. It ain't tickets, but it's a rare experience.

Answer (score 3):

No official explanation is given as to how Ross obtained the tickets. When Phoebe [asks](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=friends&episode=s08e10), he says

> Ross: I got Sting tickets!
>
> Phoebe: Oh, my God, I do love you! How did you do it?
>
> Ross: Well, let's just say: Ross can.

Knowing Ross, he probably found someone who was willing to sell and he bargained for it. We don't know and overall, we shouldn't care how, the point is he got the tickets and Phoebe can go to the concert.

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping for something more solid, but guess it just doesn't exist. :)

Comment: I always assumed that since we know Ross isn't above using devious tactics to get what he wants, he threatened to tell the school about Sting's son bullying his and when asked what he wanted for his silence, got the tickets.